# Show data in "bootstrap-table", from the data received from the controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, bootstrap-table

From the controller in Laravel I send the data to the view in this way

```
public static function index(): Factory|View
    {
        $products = Products::where('visible',true)->get();
        return view('products.list',compact('products'));
    }
```

In the blade view I previously used data-url to receive the information from an endpoint, but I want to show the data received from the controller that will be in $products

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')

    <div id="list-test">

        <table
            id="tabla-listado-productos"
            data-locale="es-ES"
            data-toggle="table"
            data-pagination="true"
            data-search="true"
            data-filter-control="true"
            data-show-search-clear-button="true"
            data-mobile-responsive="true">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="id">id</th>
                <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>


    </div>
@endsection

@section('script')

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var productos = @json($productos);

            console.log(productos);

            $('#tabla-listado-productos').bootstrapTable({
                data: productos,
            });
        });
        

    </script>

@endsection
```

If I do a console.log of $products in the blade view I see the data.

```
0:{id: 1, name: 'car test number 1', …}
1:{id: 2, name: 'car number 2', …}
length:2\[\[Prototype\]\]:Array(0)
```

search information in mutiple sites

Comment: If you just go through the documentation, it'd help. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade
Loop over the variable using @foreach and print your html.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking to make a loop.  I try to make the table have as its source a variable that contains the information, using bootstrap-table

Comment: I see, maybe try the `data` attribute? You might need to do some formatting of the data that is coming. https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#data

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the variable as `$products` in your controller, but you're trying to access it as `productos` in your Blade view. Make sure the variable names match.